# how to add id to bootstrap formhelper datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-helpers, bootstrap-form-helper

How do I set the id in the input field on bootstrap formhelper plugin.

```
<label for="daterange" >From</label>
<div class="bfh-datepicker"  data-name="daterange" data-format="m-d-y" data-max="today" data-close="false"> </div>
```

I have checked the documentation and there is nothing like data-id that could set the id of the input field.

Answer (score 3):

This is straight-forward:

```
<div class="bfh-datepicker" id="mydatepicker">
</div>
```

Event handler:

```
$('#mydatepicker').on('change.bfhdatepicker', function(e) {
  alert('Date changed: ' + $('#mydatepicker').val());
});
```

Comment: That was not my question. I want an id for the input field that it generates so that i can target it and use event handlers.

Comment: I tried your method before and it didn't generate any id for the input field.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate any id for the input field"?? You specify the id, and then write the event handlers for that particular id.

Comment: when you use $('#mydatepicker').bfhdatepicker('toggle'); it generates a list of tags including the input field which stores the date values from the date-picker. This input field doesn't have any id associated with it. I want to be able to create an id for this field.

Comment: This particular field 
<input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="" readonly="">

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Hi, @Bazinga777 i also want the same thing, did you find any solution?